# Pairing elements in a set!

Tags: combinatorics

The n elements $a_1 , a _2 ,...., a_n$ are paired into n pairs $P_1 , P_2 ,... P_n$ satisfying $P_i$ and $P_j$ have common element if and only if $a_i$ and $a_j$ are paired. Prove that each of the n element $a_1 , a _2 ,...., a_n$ belong just 2 element pairs.Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: What are your thoughts? What did you try?

Comment: I tried construct a table with $P_i$ being rows and $a_i$ being columns. But it doesn’t work for me.

Comment: Can you give any hint or solution to this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could try to interpret your pairings as the edges of a graph, and look at the dual graph.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** In the incidence matrix that you set up, count the number of row pairs and column pairs.

**Hint:** The condition that "$P_i, P_j$ have common element iff $a_i, a_j$ are paired" means that the number of row pairs is equal to the number of column pairs.

> Set up the typical incidence matrix inequality, and apply the equality case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: Were you able to work it out? It's quite a nice setup. I was wondering how to get the conclusion, and it just fell out.

Comment: Yes , thanks to the hint. Your hint helped me a lot!

Comment: @PeerakornTrechakachorn In that case, please upvote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: My reputation is less than 15. I already voted but it doesn’t count. Sorry